# How to manipulate tab groups with the keyboard in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard

I see you can create a new vertical tab group by assigning a keyboard shortcut to Window.NewVerticalTabGroup.

I am looking for the keyboard shortcuts to do the following actions:

1. Move windows between vertical tab groups
2. Close a vertical tab group (reset the view back to a single code file, the opposite of Window.NewVerticalTabGroup).

Are these actions possible using the keyboard? Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With some help from Microsoft, I got 75% there with stock Visual Studio 2010. Here are the shortcuts available.

- **Window.NewVerticalTabGroup** splits the window vertically
- **Windows.MovetoPreviousTabGroup** and **Windows.MovetoNextTabGroup** move windows between tab groups, as desired.

The only thing stock Visual Studio is missing is a shortcut to immediate close the tab group (move all tabs to one group). However, using **Windows.MovetoPreviousTabGroup** and **Windows.MovetoNextTabGroup** to move all the tabs out of one group will close it.

For those willing to install an (official Microsoft) extension, [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/?SRC=Home) solves that last 25% by adding commands **Window.MoveAllToNextTabGroup** and **Window.MoveAllToPreviousTabGroup**, as well as adding a ton of new functionality for tabs!